# Loopback Remote Method Callback not working

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

Okay citizens of the internet, I need some help... My super-simple Remote Method isn't firing the callback.  Instead I get this error message:

```
/maestro/common/models/datalog.js:11
                cb(null, err || 'success');
                ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at /maestro/common/models/datalog.js:11:11
```

The model:

```
module.exports = function(Datalog) {

    Datalog.logdata = function(description, errordetails, errormsg, severity, cb) {
        Datalog.create(
            {
                description: description,
                errordetails: errordetails,
                errormsg: errormsg,
                severity: severity
            }, function(err, res) {
                cb(null, err || 'success');
            }
        );
    }

    Datalog.remoteMethod(
        'logdata', 
        {
            accepts: [
                {arg: 'description',  type: 'string'},
                {arg: 'errordetails', type: 'string'},
                {arg: 'errormsg',     type: 'string'},
                {arg: 'severity',     type: 'string'}
            ],
            returns: {arg: 'log', type: 'string'}
        }
    );

};
```

The file calling the method:

```
logdata = require('./server/server.js').models.datalog.logdata;
logdata('my test success', '', 'test success', 'info');
```

Why is loopback not passing the callback?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong at first glance. Can you check the argument values passed in by loopback on line 4 to see if the last arg is a callback? ie) `console.log(arguments)` on line 4.

Comment: { '0': 'my test success',
  '1': '',
  '2': 'test success',
  '3': 'info' }

Comment: It looks like the callback is not passed into the remote method, but all of the data appears to be... Can you also post the URL you're hitting on your API and any request body?

Comment: It's updated in the question.

Comment: I think I just realized the problem... the 'returns' object only applies to an API request, so if I want a callback when calling it directly, I have to provide that callback when I call it, don't I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the remote method only applies to a request through the API endpoint. If you're calling it directly, provide your own callback.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of anyone who is reading this. You can leverage on loopback.lib.utils to create a new callback function for you.

Simply add

```
const utils = require('loopback/lib/utils');
```

and inside your function

```
cb = cb || utils.createPromiseCallback();
```